# Keep previous requests in php

Tags: php, session, request

**Happy new year!**

I'd like to do something which I don't know if is possible and I don't know how to look for it:

I have a form with a list of inputs, which can be infinite. The form is hosted under a url, and the inputs are sent for processing to a server with a different url.

User fills in the 1st input and a request is sent to the server as an array:
`[1st]`

Then user fills in the 2nd input and the request is sent like this:
`[1st, 2nd]`

Similarly, after N inputs, the request looks like:
`[1st, 2nd, ......, Nth]`

**And here is my question:**
Is there any way to send just the last input to the server and have the server remembering the previous requests?

Thank you in advance

Comment: use `session` to get it done

Comment: But the urls are different. Is this not a problem?

Comment: nope its not a problem

Comment: Thank you so much!